# Ubuntu 16.04 - Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Tags: apt

So far the best way to get it working without breaking a possible background running installation ( as it could happen by removing the lock file), is stopping the service using apt:

Error:

```
# sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`
```

Solution:

```
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily.timer
```

Comment: after upgrading the system I suggest re-enabling it, as the bug locking it could be fixed with the upgrade.

`systemctl enable apt-daily.timer`

I haven't verified this error gets fixed after upgrading.

I'll add a new comment once I have that verified.

Comment: If you have a solution, post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm new posting.
I saw the other thread you mention but it doesn't include this solution and I can't post it due reputation points.

Feel free to post it on that thread if you want.

Just trying to provide a better solution.

Comment: I have unprotected it for now, you can post it as an answer now.